# How does Reverse String Slicing works in Python?

Tags: python, string, slice

I would like to know how does Reverse String Slicing works. For example

```
name = 'Python'
print(name[4:1])
```

This code wouldn't give me any result, not even any error.
What is actually happening here?

But if I write

```
print(name[4:1:-1])
```

It will give the result as "oht"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing)

Comment: print(name[4:-1])

Answer (score 0):

1st example is not giving you any result, because you start off with index 4 and you want to go to index 1 (0, because 1 is excluded) - which is kind of impossible. Default step is 1.

2nd example starts from index 4, ends on index 1, which is excluded. Step in this example is -1, that is why the result is 'oht'.

```
index of 'Python':
0 1 2 3 4 5
P y t h o n

# 1 is excluded
```

Python slicing works that way:

```
name = 'Python'
print(name[start_from_index:go_to_index:step_of_slicing])
```

is that clear for you?

Comment: Oh ok so the 1st code is just not how the python works, it can't go back with a step of +1. I get it, but why it's still not giving me an error?

Comment: @Manas read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing